# How to find out postgis.backend?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

How can I find out which  postgis.backend (geos or sfcgal) I have?

Comment: Can you expand the question whether you need a code example for automatic look-up, or where to look up what you have installed manually? And maybe add what OS you are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to extract the versions from the postgis_full version SQL command. See http://www.postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/PostGIS_Full_Version.html for an example.